# How to match only numerical email addresses

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I match only numerical email addresses?

I'm testing against the following email addresses:

```
12345839223@gmail.com <-- want this  
38482934934@gmail.com <-- want this  
abcaasd@gmail.com     <-- don't want this  
asdasd123@gmail.com   <-- don't want this  
123asdasd@gmail.com   <-- don't want this
```

I tried the following regex, but it matches some addresses with letters.

`([0-9])+(@+)`

Comment: Did you want to return the number part of the email, or just check if it's valid or not?

Comment: It captures some with letters because you need an anchor on the left side. You may want to add what it captures for the wrong cases – for example, I suspect `123@` for `asdasd123@gmail.com`.

Comment: Try this if you just need to match it: `^\d+@`.  https://regex101.com/r/eX2uQ5/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex `/^\d+(?=@)/` will achieve this for you. As you can see from the image below, it looks for the start of the line followed by one or more digits followed by an "@" symbol.

[image]

Here's a [RegEx101 test case](https://regex101.com/r/oR7cQ5/2) for reference

```js
var emails = [
  '12345839223@gmail.com',
  '38482934934@gmail.com',
  'abcaasd@gmail.com',
  'asdasd123@gmail.com',
  '123asdasd@gmail.com'
];

function emailNum(email) {
    return (/^\d+(?=@)/.exec(email)||[false])[0];
    // return the match if it exists or false
}

for(var i in emails) document.write(emails[i]+': '+emailNum(emails[i])+'<br>');
```

Comment: Using a positive look-ahead for the `@` would pare the result down to just the email ID. https://regex101.com/r/oR7cQ5/2

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you could have a function like this:

```js
function isNumberEmail(email) {
    return /^\d+@.*\./.test(email)
}

emailsToTest = ["12345839223@gmail.com",
"38482934934@gmail.com",
"abcaasd@gmail.com",
"asdasd123@gmail.com",
"123asdasd@gmail.com"]

emailsToTest.forEach(function(email) {
  document.write(email + " - " + isNumberEmail(email))
  document.write("<br>")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to test if the first part of the email is a number:

```js
function test( val ) {
  var first = val.match(/^([^@]+)/g)[0];
  return /^\d+$/g.test(first);
}

console.log(test('12345@email.com'));
console.log(test('12345678@email.com'));
console.log(test('abc12345@email.com'));
console.log(test('12345abc@email.com'));
```

Comment: I don't see the need for two separate tests. Can you clarify?

Answer (score -1):

I *think* this will work, wouldn't mind if someone can verify. Adds `@` to capture group

`/([1-9][0-9]*)+(@)/g`

Edit: `^\d+@` works as per @dustmouse's comment

Comment: There are some very cool tools online. Check [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com) or [regexr.com](http://regexr.com), for an example.

Comment: You should anchor it if the input is the whole email. Is `0` not valid to start?

Comment: @AndersonPimentel I'm using regexr to test but thanks